# Как реализовать списковое включение без многократного вызова функции

Tags: python

Коллеги, **дисклеймер**. *Есть вопрос, для которого я придумал абстрактный и совершенно бестолковый, с точки зрения реализации, пример. Пример этот служит исключительно для иллюстрации моего вопроса, а не является примером хорошего решения.*

Вот пример:

```
import random

random.seed(123)

def test_random(len):
    return [random.randint(0, 10) ** 2 for _ in range(len)]

print ([test_random(10)[i] for i in range(3)])
```

Есть функция, которая генерирует и возвращает некую коллекцию, к элементам которой можно обратится по индексу/ключу.  Список, словарь, кортеж - не важно, в примере я использовал список, для простоты иллюстрации. При одинаковых входных данных, функция возвращает одинаковый результат. Мы, с помощью спискового/словарного включения, пытаемся сгенерировать какую-то другую коллекцию, на основе возвращенной из этой функции коллекции. Проблема очевидна - при такой реализации мы запрашиваем функцию **каждый раз** для каждой итерации спискового включения, вместо того, чтобы один раз получить объект и обращаться уже к нему.

**Вопрос.**

Возможна ли реализации подобной логики без многократных обращений к функции и **без предварительного введения временной переменной**, в которую я верну результат работы функции?

Comment: Если функция каждый раз при одних и тех же параметрах возвращает одни и те же данные (не как в примере в вопросе случайные данные) - добавьте кэширование через декоратор [@cache из functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache). Тогда результат будет вычисляться один раз, и при одних и тех же параметрах просто доставаться из кэша.

Comment: @insolor да, спасибо за подсказку. Действительно, в примере данные случайные, а в реальной задаче логика однозначная, сейчас уточню в вопросе. Спасибо за наводку, посмотрю в эту сторону.

Comment: @insolor Вещь! Работает! Благодарю! Если есть необходимость - напишите ответ, я плюсану.

Comment: Добавил ответом

Comment: А я не могу выбрать все ответы как лучшие? :) Я в растерянности.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov insolor больше всех старался над ответом, мне кажется )

Comment: Друзья, выражается чрезвычайная благодарность и безмерное уважение insolor, CrazyElf и Stanislav Volodarskiy. Все три ответа и, что не менее важно, комментарии добавили мне в арсенал массу понимания и классный синтаксис. Плюсанул все три ответа и, была бы возможность, все три отметил бы лучшими. Но так как такой возможности нет, то отмечу insolor, во-первых, за то, что он хотел отсидеться в комментариях, а я его затащил в ответы и, во-вторых, как сказал CrazyElf "insolor больше всех старался" :) Большое вам всем спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если функция возвращает один и тот же результат при одних и тех же входных данных, можно использовать кэширование, чтобы результат не вычислялся постоянно заново при каждом вызове функции.

Вариант с декоратором [`@cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)

```
from functools import cache
import random

random.seed(123)


@cache
def test_random(len):
    return [random.randint(0, 10) ** 2 for _ in range(len)]


print([test_random(5) for i in range(3)])
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 16, 1, 36, 16], [0, 16, 1, 36, 16], [0, 16, 1, 36, 16]]
```

Минус тут в том, что если это функция внутри библиотеки, то пользователь может не знать о наличии кэша, и пытаться добавить свои оптимизации. Т.е. есть неочевидность внутренней реализации.

Чтобы было очевидно, можно вручную добавить кэширующий вариант функции тем же декоратором, только используя его как функцию:

```
def test_random(len):
    return [random.randint(0, 10) ** 2 for _ in range(len)]


cached_test_random = cache(test_random)

print ([cached_test_random(5) for i in range(3)])
```

Если нужна возможность очистки кэша, нужно использовать декоратор [`@lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), тогда кэш можно будет очищать с помощью метода `cache_clear()`, который этот декоратор добавляет функции:

```
import random
from functools import lru_cache

random.seed(123)


@lru_cache
def test_random(len):
    return [random.randint(0, 10) ** 2 for _ in range(len)]


print([test_random(5) for i in range(3)])

test_random.cache_clear()
```

Answer (score 8):

Как вариант можно ещё один цикл `for` по списку из одного элемента в списковое включение вставить. Хотя кэширование, наверное, лучше. А ещё лучше - предварительно запомнить значение в переменную и потом её использовать. Вообще списковые включения - они не для сложных вещей. Если без включения код не получается написать, то это нормально, не нужно всё к ним сводить.

```py
print([data[i] for data in [test_random(10)] for i in range(3)])
```

Лучше всё же в явном виде:

```py
data = test_random(10)
print([data[i] for i in range(3)])
```

Comment: Так тоже прекрасно! Я б не догадался вернувшийся список положить в список. Спасибо! Но Вы считаете, как я понял, что из всех трех вариантов (1. Кэш 2. Вернувшийся список в списке 3. Предварительная переменная) - все таки лучше ввести предварительную переменную? Из каких соображений? Быстрее? Или код понятней?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov "Явное лучше неявного", ага, понятный код - это одно из основных требований к программисту. )  Нет, если например у вас функция точно детерминированная (а не рандомная) и используется не только в данном куске кода, то кеширование - прекрасный вариант. А вот если вам точно нужно, чтобы тут функция вызвалась и больше нигде она не используется, то я за временную переменную. Кстати, не нужно забывать, что кэш требует для своей работы памяти, он не "бесплатный". Конечно, для данного случая он будет мелкий и незаметный, но случаи то разные бывают.

Comment: Про память для кэша - важный комментарий. В реальной задаче возвращаемая коллекция огромная. Там словарь списков, каждый из списков может быть десятки или даже сотни тысяч флоатов и самих ключей может быть несколько десятков. Правильно ли я понимаю, что как введение дополнительной переменной для возвращаемого значения так и кэш, по затратам на память приблизительно будут одинаковыми?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, да. Только временная переменная освободит память, когда вы покинете область видимости, а кеш никогда память назад не отдаст. Обменивать строку кода на вечную глобальную переменную - так себе идея.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Ну вроде бы да. Просто переменные по выходу из области видимости автоматом утилизируются и память освобождается. Если это происходит внутри короткой функции, то думать об очистке памяти, занимаемой временной переменной, обычно не нужно. А вот функции обычно видимы глобально и кэш, привязанный к функции, будет занимать память, пока программа не закончится, либо пока его целенаправленно не почистят (там есть специальная функция `cache_clear()` в `lru_cache`, есть ли она в просто `cache` я не уверен). Это нужно помнить.

Answer (score 8):

[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) позволяет сохранить результат вычисления в параметре и затем использовать его много раз:

```
print((lambda lst: [lst[i] for i in range(3)])(test_random(10)))
```

[:=](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) сохраняет значение в начале кортежа, используется в конце кортежа. Технически ничем не отличается от предварительного введения временной переменной:

```
print((lst := test_random(10), [lst[i] for i in range(3)])[1])
```

Comment: Прикольный вариант!

Comment: Класс! Первый вариант - топчик! Второй тоже отличный с точки зрения синтаксиса, я бы так не смог, но переменная остается.